# Let p be a prime and k a positive integer such that $a^k$mod p = a mod p for all integers a. Prove that p - 1 divides k - 1.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, fermat-numbers

> Let p be a prime and k a positive integer such that $a^k$mod p = a mod
>   p for all integers a. Prove that p - 1 divides k - 1.

I think I need to use Fermat's Little Theorem, and I can get  $a^k$mod p =  $a^p$mod p, and I think it follows that  $a^{k-1}$mod p = $a^{p-1}$mod p = 1, but from there I'm stumped.

I think it follows that $a^{k-1}$ = m$a^{p-1}$, but why couldn't m be a fraction, i.e. k - 1 divides p - 1 but not the other way around?

Comment: You need more than Fermat's Little Theorem...you have to use the existence of an element of order $p-1$.  See, eg, [Primitive Roots](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807290/proof-of-existence-of-primitive-roots)

Comment: By the way, 1289671298371298379182 is a semiprime.

Answer (score 2):

The OP's solution is incorrect.  This deduction is flawed:

> "Multiplying both sides by $a^{k-1}$
>   $$a^{k-1}({a^{p-1}})^m=1a^{k-1} \implies a^{(k-1)+m(p-1)}=a^{k-1} \implies (k-1)+m(p-1) = k-1$$
>   by the definition $x$ mod $(p-1)$".

Here is a different approach.  Let $k-1=(p-1)q+r$ for some non-negative integers $q$ and $r$ with $r<p-1$.  If $r\neq 0$, then we have by Fermat's little theorem that
$$a^{r+1}\equiv a^{r+(p-1)q+1}= a^{k}\equiv a\pmod{p}.$$
Therefore, the polynomial $x^{r+1}-x$ is of degree $r+1<p$, but it has $p$ roots in the Galois field $\operatorname{GF}(p)$.  This is impossible, so $r=0$ must be the case.

Comment: Can this be proved without using the Galois field?

Comment: Yes, see lulu's comment.  Since there exists a primitive root $g$ modulo $p$, $g^k\not\equiv1\pmod{p}$ for any positive integer $k<p-1$.  But with $a=g$, we have $g^{r+1}\equiv g\pmod{p}$, or $g^r\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, but $r<p-1$.  That is, $r=0$.

Comment: How about without a Galois field and without a primitive root? My textbook includes neither of these but has pretty much this exact question.

Comment: How about induction?  Let $f$ be any function of integers.  Define $\Delta f(n)=f(n+1)-f(n)$.  Then, $\Delta^k f$ denotes the $k$-time iteration of $\Delta$.  For example, $$\Delta^2f(n)=\Delta (\Delta f)(n)=\Delta f(n+1)-\Delta f(n)=f(n+2)-2f(n+1)+f(n).$$

Comment: Prove that $\Delta^k n^k=k!$ and $\Delta^l n^k=0$ for $l>k$.  If $n^{r+1}\equiv n\pmod{p}$ holds for any integer $n$, then $\Delta^{r+1}n^{r+1}\equiv \Delta^{r+1}n\pmod{p}$.  If $r>0$, then $\Delta^{r+1}n=0$, but $\Delta^{r+1}n^{r+1}=(r+1)!$.  So, we have $$(r+1)!\equiv 0\pmod{p}.$$  This contradicts the assumption that $r<p-1$.  This proof is as elementary as I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

Another proof would be to consider the group $U(p)$ of [multiplicative units in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) $\mathbb Z / p \mathbb Z$.  For $p$ prime the order of $U(p)$ is $p-1$.  Since $p$ is prime, $U(p)$ is cyclic (see [Keith Conrad's exposition](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/cyclicmodp.pdf)) and so it has elements of all orders $d$ dividing $p-1$.

If $a$ is such an element of order $d$ then our hypothesis is that $a^{k-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$, and so $|a|=d$ divides $k-1$.  So any divisor of $p-1$ is a divisor of $k-1$, hence $p-1$ divides $k-1$.

This avoids Galois theory, unless of course you used Galois theory to prove that $U(p)$ is cyclic.  But that can be avoided because all we really needed was that $U(p)$ has an element of order $q$ for each prime $q$ dividing $p-1$, which is guaranteed by [Cauchy's theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory))

Answer (score -1):

I figured out my own question. Here is is for anyone else that wants to know (maybe my classmates...)

By FML, $a^p=a$ mod $p$.

$a^p$ mod $p=a$ mod $p$

multiplying both sides by $a^{-1}$ we get:

$a^{-1}a^p=a^{-1}a$ $\implies$ $a^{p-1}=1$.

$a^{p-1}=1$ (mod $p$)

Taking each each side to the m$^{th}$ power:

$({a^{p-1}})^m=1^m \implies ({a^{p-1})}^m=1$

Multiplying both sides by $a^{k-1}$

$a^{k-1}({a^{p-1}})^m=1a^{k-1} \implies a^{(k-1)+m(p-1)}=a^{k-1} \implies (k-1)+m(p-1) = k-1$

by the definition $x$ mod $(p-1)$ iff $x=q(p-1)+r$, so

$(k-1)+m(p-1) = k-1 \implies (k-1)$ mod $(p-1)=k-1$

By hypothesis we have $a^k$=a mod p. Like in the beginning,

$a^k$=a mod p $\implies$ $a^{-1}a^k$= $a^{-1}$a mod p $\implies$ $a^{k-1}$ = 1 mod p

Substituting $(k-1)$ mod $(p-1)$ for $k-1$ we get:

$a^{(k-1) \textrm{ mod } (p-1)} = 1$ mod $p = a^0$ mod $p= a^{0\textrm{ mod }(p-1)}$mod $p$

so, $(k-1)$ mod $p = 0 $mod $p$

By definition, this means that

$(k-1)=m(p-1)$, i.e. that $p-1$ divides $k-1$. $\square$

Comment: How did you get from $a^{(k - 1) + m(p - 1)} = a^{k - 1}$ to $(k - 1) + m(p - 1) = k - 1$?