# $x^k\equiv1 \pmod{p}$ for all nonzero $x$, then $p-1$ divides $k$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Came across this question in The Art and Craft of Problem Solving.

**Question:**
Let $p$ be a prime. Show that if $x^k\equiv1 \pmod{p}$ for all nonzero $x$, then $p-1$ divides $k$.

I know that if $k>(p-1)$, then can use Fermat's Little Theorem to 'reduce' to $k\leq(p-1)$. Then since a primitive root exists, there is some $a$ with ord(a) $=p-1$. But the existence of primitive root needs a bit of group theory, and I am wondering if there is a more elementary solution?

**My question:** Is there alternative ways of solving this question, preferably a more elementary way.

I know there is a similar question here but I think the answer posted has mistakes.
[Let p be a prime and k a positive integer such that $a^k$mod p = a mod p for all integers a. Prove that p - 1 divides k - 1.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729727/let-p-be-a-prime-and-k-a-positive-integer-such-that-akmod-p-a-mod-p-for-all)

Comment: The existence of a primitive root follows fairly easily (though not trivially) from this statement, so I doubt there any proof of this that is significantly easier than just proving that a primitive root exists.

Comment: `But the existence of primitive root needs a bit of group theory` With only number theory you can do it. In group theory we usually apply concept of number theory instead!

Comment: @EricWofsey yes that is my thought process too

Comment: One possibility is to use that $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ is a field, so the equation $x^k=1$ cannot have more than $k$ solutions. Here the assumption is that there are $p-1$ solutions, so $k\ge p-1$. A matter of taste whether that is more elementary than calling upon the existence of a primitive root.

Comment: Your Q is not equivalent to the Q in your link. If $x^k\equiv 1 \mod p$ for all $x>0$ then $p^k\equiv 1 \mod p,$ which is impossible for prime $p$ and $k>0.$

Comment: Lat month I saw on this site a brief, very elementary proof by Gauss that a primitive root exists. I'm trying to remember it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thats a very neat way to do it! I feel its more 'natural' cause it directly deals with the number of solutions

Comment: Can this be proved without using primitive roots or using the roots of a finite field? My textbook does not include either of those but has this question.