# Corollary of Fermat's Little Theorem to $a^x \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \implies x \equiv 0 \pmod{p-1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm not sure what to call this proposition in relation to Fermat's Little Theorem (it is not the converse, though it seems related), but I am interested to know if the following holds:

$$
a^x \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \implies x \equiv 0 \pmod{p-1}
$$ for $p$ prime and $a \neq 1$.

If this does hold, what is the proof? If not, are there any conditions on $x$ required in order to have $a^x \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$?

Comment: Do you know group theory ?

Comment: No...$1^2\equiv 1 \pmod 5$, for instance.

Comment: We need this to be true for *all* $a$ (or at least for carefully chosen $a$) to get the conclusion. Otherwise, not only is $a=1$ a counterexample, but so are more subtle cases like $13^4 \equiv 1 \pmod {17}$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to have $a \neq 1$. I will edit the question.

Comment: What about $a=13$? Will you edit this, too?

Comment: $2^3\equiv 1 \pmod 7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each prime $p$, there exists a *primitive root* $r$ which has the property you want: $$r^x \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \implies x \equiv 0 \pmod{p-1}.$$
For example, if we work modulo $7$, $3$ is a primitive root, because
\begin{align}
   3^0 &\equiv 1 \pmod 7 \\
   3^1 &\equiv 3 \pmod 7 \\
   3^2 &\equiv 2 \pmod 7 \\
   3^3 &\equiv 6 \pmod 7 \\
   3^4 &\equiv 4 \pmod 7 \\
   3^5 &\equiv 5 \pmod 7 \\
   3^6 &\equiv 1 \pmod 7 \\
\end{align}
so the powers of $3$ have a period of exactly $6$. It follows that $2$ will *not* work mod $7$, because $$2^3 \equiv (3^2)^3 \equiv 3^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 7.$$

[This MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/807301) gives a short proof of the existence of primitive roots modulo any prime $p$.