# Let $p$ be a prime. Prove that $x^m \bmod p = 1$ has at most $m$ solutions for $x \in U(p)$ using only group theory (no polynomials allowed)

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

This is **part of a homework problem** I am working on. In light of this, please **do not post an entire solution**.  I've been told that we do not have to use anything but Fermat's little theorem and a bit of group theory to prove this result. And I'm honestly out of ideas on how to do it. Every resource I've found seems to suggest that polynomial roots and field theory is necessary.

Comment: What is $U(p)$?  $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ or the group of $p^{\mathrm{th}}$ root of unity in $\mathbb C$?

Comment: It is $(Z/pZ)^*$

Answer (score 2):

We can try to "hide" the polynomial part, for example: look at the [Vandermonde determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) (the polynomial is hidden here)
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}1&x_1&x_1^2&\dots&x_1^m\\1&x_2&x_2^2&\dots&x_2^m\\1&x_3&x_3^2&\dots&x_3^m\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\1&x_{m+1}&x_{m+1}^2&\dots&x_{m+1}^m\end{bmatrix}=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq m}(x_j-x_i)
$$
If $x_1,\dots,x_{m+1}$ are solutions to $x^m\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, then the matrix has two identical columns (mod $p$) so LHS is $\equiv 0\pmod{p}$.  So $p$ must divide one of the factor on the RHS.

Comment: Holy cow! Yes, maybe we could use linear algebra to prove this.. I'm not sure. However, this problem came up in the first few weeks of my abstract algebra course and my prof insisted that we didn't need to use anything advanced. In spite of that, it's interesting that there is a way to avoid the polynomials, in a sense. Thanks for your response!

Comment: I don't think that repeating one [common proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25828/242) of Lagrange's theorem should count as avoiding use of it. The exercise clearly intends other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Rule Number 1. $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic, generated by some element $a$ of order $p-1$. So whatever solution you are after, it must be a power of $a$.

Comment: Can you prove that $(Z/pZ)^*$ is cyclic without using polynomials?

Comment: @farleyknight: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807290/proof-of-existence-of-primitive-roots) you go.

Comment: @QuangHoang: That uses polynomials (with the use of Lagrange's polynomial congruence theorem)

Comment: @user10354138 My bad. [Here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=xlIfdGPM9t4C&lpg=PR3&hl=ja&pg=PA105&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) is another one in *Elementary number theory*, it's gotta be polynomial-free :-).

Comment: @QuangHoang: It uses IV.4.c which is Lagrange's polynomial theorem :-)  I don't believe a truly "polynomial-free" proof exists.